# Preserve file during docker build like buildkit

Tags: mongodb, docker, dockerfile

I have MongoDB DB dump files in `dump` directory and the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM mongo:4.2.6-bionic as base
COPY dump /dump
COPY restore.sh /restore.sh
RUN chmod u+x /restore.sh
RUN /restore.sh

FROM base
COPY --from=base /data /data
CMD ["mongod"]
```

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# restore.sh
mongod&
mongorestore
```

When I build it using `docker build -t myDb .`, the Database files inside `/data` is missing in next layer itself. But when I build using `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build -t myDb .`, it is preserved during multistage build also.

(Docker version 19.03.8)